# What is the name of the phenomenom where faces get stretched to the middle of the screen?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to make my own 3D view in java without the use of any imported libraries. It has been going really well for me except for the fact that if I'm positioned in a certain way some of my edges get stretched to the middle of the screen. a reference image: [image]

The gun render's completely fine in the front part, but when I'm looking at it from this angle it looks like some of my edges get stretched to my viewto point. I want to google information on what other people have done to fix it, but I have no idea what this phenomenom is named.

I'm not looking for an answer on how to fix it, but on the name of the phenomenom because I'm trying to learn as much as possible by myself.

I'm pretty sure this is a wellknown problem and I just can't remember the name of it.

Answer (score 1):

I've *never* seen a specific term regularly used to describe this artifact. "Stretching to infinity" (as in the object gets stretched to infinity) is probably the most common phrase I've heard used to describe the problem.

One of the most common causes of this problem is bad or uninitialized data in a vertex or index buffer, usually caused by a failure to compute the correct size of a vertex or index buffer, or the correct number of elements being rendered based on the primitive topology.